# Как реализовать поворот background?

Tags: html, css

Делал ромбы(просто повернул квадраты), а от нужно вставить в каждый ромб картинку, ток проблема в том что она перевернута получается . Подскажыте пожалуйста кто такое уже делал :

Как обратно повернуть картинку ?

И как сделать чтоб при на видении ховер закрашивал ромб (ток половину) ?

Вот мой код :

```css
@charset "utf-8";


html, body {
 
 width: 1920px;
 text-align: center;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 
}



.top_baner {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(../img/baner_top.png);
    padding: 155px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.top_baner > .content_wrapper{
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 width: 1214px;
}

.top_baner > .content_wrapper > .top_line {
    width: inherit;
    background-image: url(../img/Top_logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 81px;
}


.top_baner > .content_wrapper > .top_line > p {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 63px 0 0 42px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.top_baner > .content_wrapper > h1 {

    margin: 207px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.top_baner > .content_wrapper > h2 {
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.top_baner > .content_wrapper > hr {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    border: none;
    height: 1px;
    background: white;
    margin: 40px 0px auto;
}



.top_baner > .content_wrapper > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    width: 157px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 5.5;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}


.second_block {
 width:1920px;
 height:1200px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 background:#f6f6f6;
}

/*Second_block*/

.second_block > .content_wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 width: 1214px;
}



.second_block >  .left_block {
 float:left;
 width:441px;
 margin: 284px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0 353px 0;
 text-align: left;
 padding-right: 0px;
}





.left_block > h1 {
 font-size:53px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
}




.left_block > hr {
 display: block;
 width: 20px;
 border: none;
 height: 1px;
 background: #000000;
 margin: 16px 0 auto;
}



.left_block > h2 {
 font-size:18px;
 margin: 55px 0 0  auto;
 padding:0;
}


.right_block {
 float: right;
 width: 1126px;
 display: inline-block;
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(316deg);
 top: -597px;
 right: 26px;
}


.second_block > .right_block > .firsrt_bloks > li{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin: 0 0 auto;
 padding:0;
}

.second_block > .right_block > .sekond_block > li{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin: 0 0 auto;
 padding:0;
}



.second_block >  .right_block > ul  > li > a {
 width: 193px;
 height: 193px;
 padding:0;
 margin: 10px 0px  0 10px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

.firsrt_bloks {*/;
 /* padding-top: 112px; */
 /* padding-bottom: 525px; */
 clear: both;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding: 0 0  0 0;
 height: 206px;
 margin-right: 0;
}

.second_block {
    width: 1920px;
    height: 890px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}


.left_block > h1 {
    font-size: 53px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.second_block > .left_block > hr {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    border: none;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000000;
    margin: 16px 0 auto;
}

.second_block > .left_block > h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 55px 0 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.right_block {
    float: right;
    width: 1126px;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(316deg);
    top: -597px;
    right: 26px;
}

ul.firsrt_bloks {
    padding-bottom: 525px;
    padding-top: 112px;
}

.firsrt_bloks {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 206px;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.right_block > .firsrt_bloks > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.second_block > .right_block > ul > li > a {
    width: 193px;
    height: 193px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0px 0 10px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.second_block > .right_block > ul > li > a > img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(406deg);
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom\: 1;
    padding: 1;
}

a#id1 {
}

a#id2 {
}

a#id3 {
}
a#id4 {
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 213px;
}
a#id5 {
}


a#id6 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}


a#id7 {
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 621px;
}


a#id8 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}


.right_block > ul > li > a > p {
    margin: 42px 0 0 0;
    padding: 33px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(404deg);
    width: 140px;
    clear: both;
}
.width_zone > img {
margin-bottom: 0;padding-bottom: 0;margin: -59px 0 0 0;}


.right_block > ul > li > a > p > img {
    margin: -22px 56px auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    float: left;
}

.right_block > .firsrt_bloks > li > a:hover {
    background: #28282e;
    color: white; 
 
}

/*sirt_blocked*/

.third {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1200px;
    background: #28282e;
}


.width_zone {
 margin-bottom: 75px;
 width: 600px;
 height: 320px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


a.next_slayd_1, a.next_slayd_2, a.next_slayd_3 {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 74px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
 }

.slayder {
    float: right;
    width: 600px;
    height: 445px;
}

.togles {
 background-image: url(../img/icons.png);
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 width: 222px;
 height: 47px;
 margin-left: 186px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.third > .content_wrapper {
 width:1214px;
 height:890px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.third > .content_wrapper > p {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-bottom:240px;
}

.left_block {
 float:left;
 width:441px;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 text-align: left;
 padding-right: 0px;
}

.third > .content_wrapper > .left_block > h1 {
 font-size: 53px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
 color:#FFF;
}

.third > .content_wrapper > .left_block > hr {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    border: none;
    height: 1px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 16px 0 auto;
}

.third > .content_wrapper > .left_block > h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 55px 0 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
 color:#FFF;
}

.third > .content_wrapper > .left_block > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    width: 157px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 5.5;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
 }

/*white_blog    */

.white_blog {
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 width:1920px;
 height:1200px;
 background:#FFF;
}

.content_wrapper {
 margin:0 auto;
 padding: 0 ;
 width: 1214px;
 
 
}

.white_blog > .content_wrapper > p {
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 120px;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
}


.first_line > h1 {
 float:left;
 font-size: 53px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 color:#333333;
}


.first_line > hr {
 clear: both;
 float:left;
 display: block;
 width: 20px;
 border: none;
 height: 1px;
 background: #000;
 margin: 16px 0 auto;
}

.first_line > p {
 text-align: left;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 24px 0 0 622px;
 width:406px;
}

.white_blog > .content_wrapper:last-child > p {
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 115px;
   padding: 0 0 0 0;  
}

/*  tems   */ 


.teams_block {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 width:inherit;
 height: 891px;
 background:#f6f6f6;
 
}


.teams_block > .left_block {
    float: left;
    width: 441px;
    margin: 284px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0 353px 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 0px;
}


.right_block > ul > li > a {
    width: 193px;
    height: 193px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0px 0 10px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
  background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/Steve_Jobs_Headshot_2010-CROP.jpg/250px-Steve_Jobs_Headshot_2010-CROP.jpg)

}







/*Table*/
table {
 width: 100%;
 background: white;
 color: #000;
 border-spacing: 1px;/* Расстояние между ячейками */
 background: url(../img/Bacgraund_line.png);*/;
 background-position: 50% 99%;
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


tr:nth-child(2) > td {
 background: #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
 border-color: #e5e5e5;
 }


tr:nth-child(1) > td {
 
padding-bottom: 35px;
}

tr:nth-child(2) {
 
 
 
}

tr:nth-child(3) {
 
 
 
}

tr:nth-child(4) {
}



tr:nth-child(5) {
 
}

tr:nth-child(6) {
 
}

tr:nth-child(7) {
height: 100px;color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(8) {
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(9) {
 
 
}

tr:nth-child(10) {
 
 
}


tr:nth-child(11) {
 
 
}


/*Gray_block*/


.Gray_block {
 width:1920px;
 height:1041px;
 background: #28282e;
 color: white;
}

.Gray_block > .content_wrapper {
 width:1214px;
 height:890px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 
 
}

.Gray_block > .content_wrapper > h1{
 margin:0 auto;
 padding: 142px 0 0 0;
 font-size:39px;
}

.Gray_block > .content_wrapper > p{
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 65px 0 0 0;
 text-align:center;
 width:720px;
 height:77px;
}

.Gray_block > .content_wrapper > .slayder {
    padding-top: 55px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    width: 965;
    height: 458px;
}


.controlers {
 padding-top: 55px;
} 

.controlers >.inputs:nth-child(1) {
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.inputs {
margin-left: 42px;}

tr:nth-child(3) > td {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(1) {
    padding-right: 607px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color: #e5e5e5;
}


tr:nth-child(5) > td {
    padding-top: 20px;
}




tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(1) {
padding-left: 19px;}


tr:nth-child(6) > td {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-right: 607px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

tr:nth-child(8) > td {
    /* padding-left: 56px; */
    padding-right: 571px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}


table.tables_2 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: white;
}

.tables_2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td {
    padding-bottom: 65px;
    padding-right: 600px;
}

.tables_2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td {
    text-align: center;
    color: #ef443a;
}

.tables_2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
.tables_2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
.tables_2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}


tbody > td > tr {}

tbody > tr > td {
    /* border-color: #e5e5e5; */
    padding-left: 21px;
}



input[type="radio"]:checked {
}

/*red_line*/


.red_line  {
 margin:0 auto;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 width:inherit;
 height:120px;
 text-align:center;
 color:#FFF;
 background-color:#ef4035;
 line-height: 7.5;
 font-size: 18px;
}


/* futter  */

.futter {
 height: 150px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 width: 1920px;
 background: #28282e;
 color:#727277;
 font-size:13px;
}


.futter > .content_wrapper > p {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 67px 256px 0 0;
    float: left;
}
.futter > .content_wrapper > p:nth-child(4) {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}




.right_block > ul > li > a:nth-child(4) {
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 213px;
}

.right_block > .firsrt_bloks > li > a:nth-child(6) {}

.right_block > .firsrt_bloks > li > a:nth-child(6) {}

.right_block > .firsrt_bloks > li > a.id4 {
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 213px;
}

.third  > .right_block > ul > li > #id7 {
 
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 621px;
}

.thumb {
background-image:url(../img/charle_igener.png);
position: relative;
overflow: hidden; 
}

.thumb:after {
  content: "";
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: inherit;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);


 
 
}


.right_block > .firsrt_bloks > li > a.id7 {
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 621px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="teams_block">
        <div class="left_block">
            <h1>OUR SERVICES</h1>
            <hr noshade="">
            <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tincidunt sit amet erat malesuada interdum. Aenean sodales dui quis leo fermentum scelerisque. Fusce condimentum dolor justo, ac tristique diam iaculis at.   </h2> </div>
        <div class="right_block">
            <ul class="firsrt_bloks">
                <li>
                    <a class="id1" class="rectangle">
                       
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="id2" class="rectangle">
                       
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="id3" class="rectangle">
                       
                    </a>
                </li>
                <br>
                <li>
                    <a class="id4" class="rectangle">
                       
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="id5" class="rectangle">
                        
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="id6" class="rectangle">
                        
                    </a>
                </li>
                <br>
                <li>
                    <a class="id7" class="rectangle">
                        
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  class="thumb" class="id8" class="rectangle">
                     
                    </a>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: предоставьте, пожалуйста, компактный код, затрагивающий только эту проблему - то есть один ромб, без посторонних элементов. css соответственно тоже

Comment: И к чему в вопросе метки _javascript_ и _jquery_?

Comment: приблизительно так - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ct06juyd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай ячейки `overflow: hidden;` а внутрь - засунь блоки и пропиши им `background-image`, и поверни их в обратную сторону с помощью transform rotate.

А что бы закрашивало половину - используй градиент